# 2nd meaning of "touch it and you'll be tangled up in it forever"

Tags: slang

I just heard that 
"touch it and you'll be tangled up in it forever"
has a really bad second meaning and I should not use it - can anyone explain ?

Comment: As a native speaker, I have never heard that phrase, nor do I have any clue what the unsavory implication might be. Where have you heard this phrase?

Comment: it was in a discussion where one non-native speaker wanted to express: "do not touch it, you will stick forever being responsible to repair it" - and another said not to use it because of a negative 2nd meaning - which I cannot find ...

Comment: I have never even heard the first usage... Are you sure you are quoting exactly?

Comment: _That's what she said_

Answer (score 1):

It’s usually worth checking the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tangle) for things like this. In this case, it says

> tangle
>
> The act of OR pertaining to sexual relations.

It’s the top definition and the only thing I can think your friend is alluding to. As a native speaker, I’ve never used "tangle" as innuendo.

Comment: According to Urban Dictionary, just about any word has some sexual connotation.